# shell script to conditionally add apt repository

Tags: apt, repository, scripts

I want to write a shell script that will add an apt repository.
I know that I can do it using `sudo add-apt-repository -y <repo>`.

My question is can I do it only if the repository was not added already, something like:

```
if repo was not added yet:
  sudo add-apt-repository -y <repo>
  sudo apt-get update
```

Thanks

Comment: `add-apt-repository` will only add it once; the interesting part is doing the `apt-get update` conditionally.

Comment: Have you even actually tried adding a repository twice ? What I've done just now is `add-apt-repository` for a theme twice, but that resulted only into one file in `/etc/apt/sources/sources.list.d` .Maybe it already does the checks ?

Comment: It's been a while since I tried it but IIRC it duplicates the line in the repository's list file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up writing a function to deal with ppa repositories.

```sh
add_ppa() {
  grep -h "^deb.*$1" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "Adding ppa:$1"
    sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:$1
    return 0
  fi

  echo "ppa:$1 already exists"
  return 1
}
```

I wonder if there is some more elegant way.

Comment: how to use to add ppa "deb archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) restricted multiverse"?

Answer (score 5):

I changed Itay's function so that it handles multiple parameters:

```bsh
add_ppa() {
  for i in "$@"; do
    grep -h "^deb.*$i" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
      echo "Adding ppa:$i"
      sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:$i
    else
      echo "ppa:$i already exists"
    fi
  done
}
```

To be called like this:

```bsh
add_ppa webupd8team/atom xorg-edgers/ppa ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Answer (score 2):

Now it is possible to remove the repository prior to adding it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r $REPO
sudo add-apt-repository $REPO
```