# Shell script to skip PPA if installed

Tags: bash, scripts, ppa

I would like to create a script that will add a new PPA or skip if already installed.

Someone posted this solution to a different question:

```
#!/bin/bash 

add_ppa() {
      for i in "$@"; do
        grep -h "^deb.*$i" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
          echo "Adding ppa:$i"
          sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:$i
        else
          echo "ppa:$i already exists"
        fi
      done
    }
```

[shell script to conditionally add apt repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293838/shell-script-to-conditionally-add-apt-repository#)

In my case I would like to add `ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge`, but I am not sure where I am supposed to add this in the script.

I tried `add_ppa(ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge)` but I keep getting an error saying (`ppa` is the name of my script):

```
ppa: 1: ppa: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I also tried with a space in between ppa and without the ()

```
ppa: 1: ppa: add_ppa: not found
ppa: 12: ppa: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: It would be useful to [edit] your question to include your script, making it easier to diagnose where the problems lie.

Answer (score 9):

That is a bash function, and to pass arguments to bash functions, you don't need `()`. Also, the function adds the `ppa:` prefix to its arguments, so just this would do:

```
add_ppa otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
```

Additionally, the function supports multiple arguments, so you can run it for multiple PPAs:

```
add_ppa otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge foo/bar a/b
```

---

Given that you have put the function in a script, you should either:

- source it as Zanna suggests to get the function in your shell and call the function, or
- just use the contents of the function as the script:

  ```
  #! /bin/bash
  for i in "$@"; do
    if grep -Rq "^deb.*$i" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
    then
      echo "Adding ppa:$i"
      sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:$i
    else
      echo "ppa:$i already exists"
    fi
  done
  ```

  And the call the script with the ppa name:

  ```
  ppa otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
  ```

Comment: Kind of a side note, you can drop the ``in "$@"``; `for i; do` loops over the positional parameters.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are executing the file as a script, but it's only a function definition, so the function is never called when it's run.

You don't need to add anything to it; you don't need to add the PPA anywhere inside it. You can `source` the file and then call the function in the current shell:

```
. ppa
add_ppa otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
```

(assuming the file you saved it in is called `ppa`, is in the current working directory, and has exactly the same content as the example you posted)

You could also run it as a script, if you add a line that actually calls the function. You could hard-code the PPA into it by adding a line like this at the end:

```
add_ppa otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
```

and then run the script. But that way, you'd have to edit the file every time you wanted to add a new PPA...

Instead you can call the function on all the arguments passed to the script by adding a line like this:

```
add_ppa "$@"
```

then when the script is called:

```
./ppa otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge thing/stuff etc/andSoOn
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may have made a typo in your script, specifically at the definition of the `add_ppa` function.

The error message:

```
ppa: 1: ppa: add_ppa: not found
ppa: 12: ppa: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

Indicates that add_ppa is not being recognised as a function.

It appears that you may have used `(` in place of `{` when defining the function. Correct this mistake and the function should work correctly, though it should be used as indicated in muru's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1019885/320386).